# iOS VoiceOver scrolling, inner div, 3 finger swipe up/down

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, voiceover

I am doing some VoiceOver experimentation with scrolling (the three-finger swipe up/down gesture).

My test page is at:

```
http://107.170.41.208/AccessibleHTML
```

There is a div with a scrollbar and lots of content (red background), and after that another div that is not scrollable with a lot of content (yellow background).

With the mouse I can scroll through the red background content, but using VoiceOver it skips that section.

How can I scroll through the red section content with VoiceOver?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but hopefully it's still useful to people.

Using `position: absolute` can sometimes cause some issues for screen readers as the DOM layout might not match the visual order. The VoiceOver can sometimes take the decision that it wouldn't make sense to read that first (or at all).

In that specific case you could just set the required height on the "red" `<div>` with `overflow:scroll` and it would be fine and should be readable and scroll-able.

As a more general rule, try and keep the visual order consistent with the DOM order, using `float` sparingly to change the layout slightly.

There obviously are rules somewhere dictating how and why this happens but they are tied up in Apple's code and very changeable between releases.